# passing arguments to an onchange() function

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to create an image slider, in which moving the handle on the slider will change the image to be displayed.

In the code below, I use an onchange function to dynamically update the image
(id = "image") based on the current value of slider (id = "image-slider-response").

```
     var imageGroup1 = ['imageA.jpg','imageB.jpg','imageC.jpg'];
     var slide = document.getElementById('image-slider-response');
     var imageDiv = document.getElementById("image");
     slide.onchange = function() {
         imageDiv.src = imageGroup1[this.value];
     }
```

Now, I'm trying to pass imageGroup as an argument to the onchange function to extend the code above to other image groups.
I followed this link http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/passing-arguments-to-callback-functions/ but didn't seem to work. Any suggestions to fix this?

```
    var imageGroup1 = ['imageA.jpg','imageB.jpg','imageC.jpg'];
    var imageGroup2 = ['imageD.jpg','imageE.jpg','imageF.jpg'];
    var slide = document.getElementById('image-slider-response');
    var imageDiv = document.getElementById("image");

    function myFunction(x){
        return function(){
            sliderDiv.innerHTML = slide.value;
            imageDiv.src = x[slide.value];
        }
    }
    var imageGroup = imageGroup1;
    slide.addEventListener("onchange", myFunction(imageGroup));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the callback there, there's just one thing - when using `addEventListener`, don't prefix the event with `on`: just use the plain event name.

```
slide.addEventListener("change", myFunction(imageGroup));
```